# How to unit test a python script with nested modules accepting command line arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have an example code like this. How to unit test gen_a, gen_b, gen_c,...,gen_z with different input a,b,c (through command line)? I know, my codes are terribly organized.... These modules do not take any input. So, how to set command line arguments in unit test? Thanks!

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Davidson')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--a',  type=int,   default=1,)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--b',  type=int,   default=2)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--c',  type=int,   default=3)
    return parser.parse_args()


def gen_d():
    args = parse_args()
    a = args.a
    b = args.b
    c = args.c
    '''using a,b,c to create d '''
    return d

def gen_e():
    d = gen_d()
    '''using d create e '''
    return e

def gen_f():
    e = gen_e()
    '''using e create f '''
    return f

def gen_g():
    f = gen_f()
    '''using f create g '''
    return g

'''and so on'''

def gen_z():
    y = gen_y()
    '''using y create z '''
    return z
```

Comment: These functions don't know anything about the command line arguments (which is good). You can just mock out `parse_args()` to return known values. Then you can makes assertions based on the return value of the functions.

Comment: yeah, that's the point: if I use another test.py and import the above example script, how to mock out `parse_args()`?

Answer (score 0):

The command-line is represented by a list variable in Python by the `sys.argv` variable which you can explictly set in each unit test with the arguments you want to specify.

The `parse_args()` function by default uses sys.argv as the list of arguments but you can override this by specifying an explicit list of arguments; e.g. `parser.parse_args(args=myargs)`.

**== mylib.py ==**

```python
import argparse

def parse_args(s):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Davidson')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--a',  type=int,   default=1)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--b',  type=int,   default=2)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--c',  type=int,   default=3)
    return parser.parse_args()
    
def gen_d():
    args = parse_args()
    a = args.a
    b = args.b
    c = args.c
    # using a,b,c to create d
    d = a + b + c
    return d

'''and so on'''
```

Here is sample unittest class calling your code.

**== mytest.py ==**

```python
import unittest
import sys
import mylib

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_gen_d(self):
        # mock command-line args to your script:
        sys.argv = ['python', '--a=100', '--b=20']      
        value = mylib.gen_d()
        self.assertEqual(123, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```